# Fancybox in Angular 11 slide auto starting

Tags: angular, fancybox

I am working on fancybox gallery images in Angular 11. I have managed to view my images using fancybox, but I want slides to play automatically. How can I do it? Is there any way to do it by adding a html attribute like autostart="true" ?

Here is my story feed implementations.

```
<div class="stories-feed">
<div class="columns is-multiline">

    <div class="column is-4 is-half-tablet" *ngFor="let story of stories | orderBy : '-createdDate'">

        <!--Feed item-->
        <div class="story-feed-item" id="story-item">
            <a href="{{story.imageUrl}}" title="{{story.description}}" data-demo-href="{{story.imageUrl}}"
                data-fancybox="images" attr.data-caption="{{story.description}}">
                <img class="featured-image" src="{{story.imageUrl}}" data-demo-src="{{story.imageUrl}}"
                    alt="{{story.description}}" data-caption="{{story.description}}">
            </a>
            <a class="item-meta">
                <div class="user-info">
                    <div class="small-avatar">
                        <img class="avatar" src="{{story.createdByUserPhoto}}"
                            data-demo-src="{{story.createdByUserPhoto}}" data-user-popover="10" alt=""
                            title="{{story.createdByUserName}}">
                    </div>
                    <span>{{story.createdByUserName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="item-stats">
                    <div class="stat-item">
                        <mat-icon>favorite_border</mat-icon>
                        <span>99</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat-item">
                        <mat-icon>chat_bubble_outline</mat-icon>
                        <span>23</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any

/* Models */
import { Story } from '../../../models/story/story';

@Component({
selector: 'app-story-feed',
templateUrl: './story-feed.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./story-feed.component.scss']
})

export class StoryFeedComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

@Input() stories: Story[];

ngOnInit() {
    jQuery('[data-fancybox="images"],[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
    slideShow : {
    autoStart : true
  }
 });
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How did u integrate fancy box into ur application . I am still struggling with it. Could u please share the  insites of it